# Understanding coalesce in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a question about coalesce. It's not quite clear the side effect of it. I have the following RDD:

```
JavaRDD<String> someStrings = //...
JavaRDD<String> coalescedStrings = someStrings.coalesce(100, false); //descreasing
```

So, what actually happened? If I operate on `someStrings` with some operations is it going to affect `coalescedStrings`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, what actually happened?

First of all, since `coalesce` is a Spark *transformation* (and all transformations are *lazy*), **nothing happened**, yet. No data was read and no action on that data was taken. What did happen - a **new** RDD (which is just a driver-side abstraction of distributed data) was created. This new RDD is a set of instructions for reading / transforming data, which is identical to the set of instructions called `someStrings`, except it contains one more "instruction": to repartition the data into 100 partitions. Actions / transformation on **that new RDD** (`coalescedStrings`) would use 100 partitions (which would translate into 100 tasks per stage) to perform any processing, unlike operations on `someStrings` that would use the original partition count. So the two RDDs would contain the same data (if operated upon), but partitioned differently.

> If I operate on `someStrings` with some operations is it going to affect `coalescedStrings`?

**No**, the two RDDs are completely* independent of each other - actions on one would not affect the other. `someStrings` still has its original number of partitions.

* this has some exceptions, mostly where it comes to caching: for example, if at any stage of its calculation, `someStrings` was cached, and you operate on `someStrings` before your operate on `coalescedStrings` - then subsequent operations on `coalescedStrings` would be able to use the cached results and continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

The coalesce method reduces the number of partitions in a DataFrame.
It will not affect coalescedStrings whatever operation you operate on someStrings.